# Is it worth buying compostable dog poop bags instead of plastic if I'm going to throw them in regular trash bins?

Tags: plastic, plastic-alternatives, compostable-plastic

I walk my dogs twice a day, pick up their poop with small disposable bags, and throw the bags in the first municipal trash bin I come across. They will presumably end up in a landfill.

I previously assumed it was better to buy biodegradable or compostable bags, but now I'm learning that landfills are not good for composting, so this probably doesn't really work. One article even said that they will degrade anaerobically and release methane.

The more eco-friendly bags are generally significantly more expensive, so I don't want to buy them if there's no point. Is there one?